# Extreamly high GPU usage while doing very little

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, windows, performance, gpu

Recently just switched to ubuntu from windows 10, and so far i love it! But i got a problem, when ever i do pretty much anything my gpu usage jumps close to 100% and everything becomes very laggy and sluggish, even when i just browse the web in firefox, now i didn't had this problem in windows, and i have no idea what might cause this, the problem seems to be worst when im running on battery, and not when im plugged in, though i need to do more testing about that. Is there someone who has any idea what might cause the big jump at gpu usage, any help will be much appreciated.

Love from Denmark

> Hardware:
>   Processor: Intel Core i7-6700HQ @ 3.50GHz (8 Cores), Motherboard: Acer Aspire VN7-592G, Chipset: Intel Sky Lake /DRAM, Memory: 16384MB, Disk: 128GB LITEON CV1-8B128 + 1000GB TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1, Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M 4096MB (33/405MHz), Audio: Realtek ALC255, Network: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 + Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless
>
> Software:
>   OS: Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel: 4.8.0-39-generic (x86_64), Desktop: Unity 7.4.0, Display Driver: NVIDIA 367.57, Compiler: GCC 5.4.0 20160609, File-System: ext4, Screen Resolution: 1920x1080

Comment: Laggy how?  Slow moving windows around or screen tearing when scrolling in browser?  Is the 367 the recommended/tested driver you get from the software updater /settings/ additional drivers tab?

Comment: Slow moveing windows, extremely slow when tab swi thing and video freezing constantly. Yes, i am running the recommended proprietary nvidia driver.

Comment: Check your BIOS/UEFI Settings for video control.  Start with the dedicated, then if OK, try the optimus (switches back and forth with integrated, but that's not for performance).

Comment: Can't see to find a tab for video control in my UEFI?

I have found that the problem is worst when im running on battery, when im plugged in, my gpu never goes above 50% while browsing ( which still seems high?) and there is no lag to speak off, while doing everyday task.

Comment: use `top` or `htop` to see what process is using your CPU the most. Sometimes, when I boot, I see python3 is over using my CPU.

Comment: Have checked htop, im nearly 100% sure this is purely a gpu problem.

Comment: run nvidia-settings and check the GPU/powermizer settings, maybe should be set to performance instead of adaptive or auto. Check prime profiles are set to performance.

Comment: Any news on this?